# Comparing strings first letter

Tags: java

how can i do this in java

```
if left(mystring,3)="adm" then ..
```

i've tried this but not success

```
if (mystring.charAt(3).equals("adm")) { ...
```

Could anyone tell me the correct way?

Comment: You probably want to write `if(mystring.startsWith("adm"))`

Comment: `if (mystring != null && mystring.startsWith("adm")`

Comment: See the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) of class `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Your first attempt, you cannot use `=` to perform a comparison. Also, you didn't define `left`. Your second attempt you are using 'charAt' which returns a single `char` which is a primitive and lacks methods. You could replace it with `mystring.substring(0,3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method *charAt()* returns a primitive value char, the one at the given index. You can't call a method in a char value.

You could use

```
myString.startsWith("adm")
```

Instead.

The more important point is that all these methods are extensively documented. So don't assume what a method is doing. Study its javadoc instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `substring` method

```
if (mystring.substring(0,3).equals("adm")) {
```

The `String` function `substring(int j,int i)` gives a substring of the original string from index `j` until index `i`, excluding character at `i`

Answer (score 1):

You can use startsWith(string) like this :

```
if(mystring.startsWith("adm")){...
```